# Javascript: Is there a cleaner way to extract object properties?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, jsobject, object-destructuring

I have the following JS code:

```
let obj1 = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: 3,
    prop4: 4
}

let obj2 = {
    prop1: obj1.prop1,
    prop2: obj1.prop2,
}
```

Here I create `obj2` which has certain select properties of `obj1`. Is there a cleaner/quicker way to do this than what I've done here? Some kind of destructuring hack?

Comment: `let { prop3, prop4, ...obj2 } = obj1` but that is confusing and fails if you add properties. There's no syntax for this so just create a helper function.

Comment: how about optional chaining ? you can use obj1?.prop1

Comment: are you trying to clone obj1? if so I think you want to do json.parse/stringify

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way,

```js
let obj1 = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: 3,
    prop4: 4
}

let obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1,['prop1','prop2']))
console.log(obj2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj1 = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: 3,
    prop4: 4
}

let { prop1, prop2 } = obj1

let obj2 = {
    prop1,
    prop2
}

console.log(obj2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to store all your obj1 properties to obj2. may e it will help you.

```js
let obj1 = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: 3,
    prop4: 4
}
//ES6
let obj2 = {}
for(key in obj1){
  obj2[key]= obj1[key]
}
console.log(obj2)
//ES5
let obj3 = {}
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(key){
  obj3[key]= obj1[key]
})
console.log(obj2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` way is great except that won't work for functions.
So, if you have function in your object, better to do this:

```
let obj1 = {
    prop1: function(x){console.log("hello", x)},
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: 3,
    prop4: 4
}

const keysForObj2 = ["prop1", "prop2"]

let obj2 = {};

for (key in obj1) {
    if (keysForObj2.includes(key)) {
        obj2[key] = obj1[key];
    }
}
console.log(obj2);    // Only prop2 will be present with JSON way
```

`obj2.prop1("world");`   You can't do this in **JSON** way

Answer (score 0):

You could get do it with a utility function I created.

```js
let obj1 = {
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: 2,
  prop3: 3,
  prop4: 4
}

const { pick } = rubico

const obj2 = pick(['prop1', 'prop2'])(obj1)

console.log(obj2)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rubico/index.js"></script>
```

Documentation for [pick](https://github.rubico.land#pick)